# oddp vs cl-oddp in elisp script

Tags: aliases, symbol-function

I am trying to write a short script file with elisp for the first time which will serve me to install all the required packages that I use. Thus when I change from one computer to another, I can get all the basic tools that I use daily.  My purpose here is to write some code in lisp that actually serves me.

My question is about `(oddp)` function. I can execute this in ielm. But when I try to run script from the terminal. It gives me :

> Symbol’s function definition is void: oddp

I searched a little and found another function `(symbol-function)`. If I understand correctly this function shows the real name of a function. For instance, a user defined function is actually a lambda function (described in [gnu-emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Cells.html#Function-Cells)). For the `oddp` function it is `cl-oddp` function. And when I change `oddp` to `cl-oddp` script finally started to work properly.

I am wondering 2 things :

1. Why renaming does not work ?
2. If renaming does not work then why it is used?

B.R.

p.s. I am using Aquamacs (Emacs 25.1.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you load library `cl.el` then `C-h f oddp` tells you this:

> `oddp` is an alias for `cl-oddp` in `cl.el`.
>
> `(oddp INTEGER)`
>
> Return `t` if `INTEGER` is odd.
>
> This function does not change global state, including the match data.

`oddp` is defined as an **alias** defined in `cl.el`. But your error message tells you that `oddp` is not defined. This is because `cl.el` has not yet been loaded.

`(symbol-function 'oddp)` tells you that the function definition of `oddp` is `cl-oddp`, which is a **symbol**. That symbol acts (indirectly) as a function, if its symbol-function value gets defined. It gets defined as a function (an alias to a defined function) when library `cl.el` is loaded.

If you want to use `oddp` in your code then you can load library `cl.el`.

`cl-oddp` itself is defined in `cl-lib.el` (a smaller library than `cl.el`). You can just require `cl-lib` instead of `cl`, if you use `cl-oddp` in your code instead of `oddp`.